# JQuery AJAX get data even on error

Tags: jquery, ajax

When using ajax jquery if the server responds with a 404, 400 or any 4xx http response it doesn't return the actual data returned by the url.

My application sends 400 responses with json data that contains the error.

I want my ajax to return that json into the dom, so I can see what errors occurred.

Comment: There is a `responseText` property, have you checked it?

Comment: @BlackSheep the `responseText` just returns `error`.

Comment: Where is your code? and a sample of the responseText being sent from the server?